# Graphical login as user who has no password

Tags: 19.10, mate, authentication

I'm using MATE desktop on 19.10. I've made a user who has no password, and I need to log in as them with a desktop (setting up WINE so they can play games.) When I just enter the username and press enter, it says the password is invalid. The account was created with `sudo adduser x --disabled-password`.

Comment: 19.10 is [EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) (End Of Life) and thus off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went down the wrong path:

- A "disabled password" means that the account is *locked*; that user cannot log in. You use that for system users (like syslog), or occasionally for real-human-users who are on sabbatical away from the system or let their passwords expire.
- The only supported method of password-less login is *autologin*, meaning that the system will always login to that user. It's very easy to set up in the Users and Groups control panel. See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en for step-by step instructions.
- There is no supported method by which you can select a user at the login screen, and have some require a password and some not. Either everybody uses the same autologin account, or everybody uses their own account with their own password.